# Remove text between square bracket in complicated array formula

Tags: google-sheets, brackets

I have a complicated formula that copies data from other cells on a different tab and I want to add the removal of brackets and text between them.  This information is private so I don't want it displayed on the new tab. I am working in Google Sheets.

The formula below results in copying first name, last name, and a course that meets specific criteria on another tab. The problem is that we are indicating Legal Names with brackets on the primary tab, but those legal names should NOT be displayed on the new tab. I'm sure there is a better way to write this, but it works extremely well.  I just need to add the removal of the brackets and texts between them. I know there is a way, but I can't seem to make it work with the current formula.  HELP!

=IFERROR(INDEX('7th Class List'!$C$3:$E$66,SMALL(IF('7th Class List'!$A$3:$A$66="A",ROW('7th Class List'!$A$3:$A$66)-ROW('7th Class List'!$C$3)+1),ROW(1:1))),"")

Comment: can you share a simplified example?

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 0):

its done like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\[.*\]", )
```

[image]

Comment: How/where do I add it into the formula.  Every time I add it, the formual breaks.

Comment: @ToniH try: `=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(IFERROR('7th Class List'!$C$3:$E$66,SMALL(IF('7th Class List'!$A$3:$A$66="A",ROW('7th Class List'!$A$3:$A$66)-ROW('7th Class List'!$C$3)+1),ROW(1:1))), "\[.*\]", ))`

Comment: Now I get the following error: "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in G6."    G6 is the cell below where the formula is entered.

Comment: @ToniH can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. It's confidential information. I could clear it, but you wouldn't have data to see the functionality. :(